# What does datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp do, in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and I came across this function,

```
get_hour = udf(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x / 1000.0). hour)
```

I understand that udf is a user defined function but I am unable to understand what
**datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp** does. Please explain.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: the udf converts a posix timestamp into a datetime object [Link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)

Answer (score 1):

Unix time (also known as Epoch time, POSIX time, seconds since the Epoch, or UNIX Epoch time) is a system for describing a point in time. It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch, minus leap seconds; the Unix epoch is 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 (an arbitrary date)

The datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp basically converts this posix time to a datetime object which is basically a single object having both date and time along with an optional timezone info(default: UTC):

`datetime(2011, 11, 4, 0, 0)`

Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp